# Converging or Diverging for what all cases?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Let $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider
$$
f(r,s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s \ln^r n}.
$$

- $s, r \le 0 \implies f(r,s)$ diverges
- $s=0, r < 0 \implies f(r,s)$ diverges
- $s<0, r = 0 \implies f(r,s)$ diverges

I could figure out what would happen when s and r are negative and zero
but what other cases are possible and how do you go about solving those cases?

Comment: just in case anyone finds it tough to read,inside the bracket it is ln(n)

Comment: Relevant keywords: Bertrand series.